# elegant checks test

Tags: java

basically I'm doing this :

```
private boolean preRequisitesControl() 
{
    assert(checkEnvironment());
    assert(validateRunContext());
    assert(checkLockFile());
    return true;    
}
```

And wondered if it were a correct way to do things. In the future, I know I will have to add other boolean checks so I wanted something simple to maintain and with the fail fast philosophy.

My checks do contain file existence tests, presence of environment variables  and so forth.

Any better ideas ?

Comment: Give us some context to this plz

Comment: What does that `assert()` method do?

Comment: "Better" in what way? Without context, it's difficult to say. You might, say, have a collection of interface implementations and iterate over them.

Comment: It's a console app. When it starts, it has to check pre requisistes and fail as soon as possible. 
The assert function is the standard java instruction.
Better regarding cleanness and maintainability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they're booleans, most Java developers I know would do:

```
private boolean preRequisitesControl() 
{
    return checkEnvironment() 
           && validateRunContext() 
           && checkLockFile();   
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought of that one but I loose the "exit as soon as possible feature". True enough, regarding my app, there is no real time issue but I wanted to keep this feature :).

Thanks for your input though :)

Comment: @charly's You do get the "exit as soon as possible", the evaluation will stop when it reaches the first false answer.